# create thread incompatible type

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

Hi am  trying to create a thread calling a function which takes a struct.
The problem am facing is the gcc is telling me an incompatible pointer

This is the error

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(struct sonicPins *)
```

’

The line of code relating to this error
`pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1)`;

Here is the function its trying to call

```
void* threadFunc(struct sonicPins *args)
```

The struct is defined in sonicThread.h and the main points to the struct

Above the main function I have

```
struct sonicPins *args1;
```

And in my main I have

```
args1 = malloc(sizeof(struct sonicPins));

args1->trig1 = 21;
args1->echo1 = 20;
//front right.
args1->trig2 = 16;
args1->echo2 = 12;
//rear left;
args1->trig3 = 26;
args1->echo3 = 19;
//rear right.
args1->trig4 = 13;
args1->echo4 = 6;
```

I have tried various ways to work around the problem but cannot find nor come up with a solution to the problem in question.

Comment: I rolled-back your edit as it made the answer below meaningless. Please don't change code after getting answers. Either post a new question or add updated code without removing the old code.

Answer (score 3):

GCC's error message is straightforward: the `pthread_create` method expects a method that accepts a `void*` argument.

Change your function to this:

```
void* threadFunc(void* sonicPinsPtr) {
    struct sonicPins* args = sonicPinsPtr;

    // rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I did have it like that but was finding I was unable to access the struct. Inside the function being called I have echo = args->echo1; Thiis returns the following error: sonicThread.c: In function ‘threadFunc’:
sonicThread.c:11:8: error: ‘echo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sonicThread.c:11:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sonicThread.c:11:19: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
sonicThread.c:11:19: error: request for member ‘echo1’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: @JamesSmith then you should show more code because this is the *correct* answer to your initial question -- take a second look at the code in this answer, of course you need a pointer to your `struct` type first...

Comment: @JamesSmith: Then inside the thread function do: `struct sonicPins * p = sonicPinsPtr;` and use `p` to access the members of `struct sonicPins` like this `p->echo1`.

Comment: There is no need to cast a `void` -pointer (here: to `struct sonicPins *`) in C, nor is it recommended to do so.

Comment: When I tested the code as you suggested I get: sonicThread.c: In function ‘threadFunc’:
sonicThread.c:8:7: error: expected expression before ‘args’
sonicThread.c:12:8: error: ‘echo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sonicThread.c:12:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: "alk" is correct, this is a [tag:c] question, so please remove the superfluous and distracting (and under special conditions even dangerous) cast. It should just read `struct sonicPins *args = sonicPinsPtr;`. @JamesSmith make sure your `struct sonicPins` is declared at the time your function uses it (so move it above the definition of your threadFunc or do a forward-declaration.)

Comment: @JamesSmith It doesn't matter where the function is *called*. This is a compiler error, the compiler processes your source code sequentially. Just make sure the compiler knows what a `struct sonicPins` *is* before it sees code using this as a type.

Comment: @JamesSmith And declare the variables `echo` and `trig`  somewhere like `int echo, trig;` before the assignment of both of them.

Comment: I resolved the expected expression before args simply by removing the if(args!=null) statement thank you for your assistance. However when I do printf("threadFunc got  value: %d\n", args->trig1);
I only  get some address rather than the integer itself.

Comment: yes I have int trig; and int Echo; at the top of the sonicThread.c if i didn't am sure it wouldn't compile. It seems the pointer is only giving an address int to trig; and 0 to Echo.